# How to query listings in Sabai Directory plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to query listings in PHP using [Sabai Directory](https://codecanyon.net/item/sabai-directory-plugin-for-wordpress/4505485) plugin. In my code, I extract the keywords from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and then intend to use them to find matching listings. Now, the problem is I need a way to assign those keywords to my listings in the first place. I tried 2 approaches:

1. **Categories**. It seems that Sabai does not support core WP categories (*does it*?), but has its own version. So if you create a Category, Sabai creates a page with a permalink for it. However, my categories are very trivial, they just have a label and a value with no content or no media; I don't want users to see category pages (e.g. `/directory/categories/chocolate`), it makes no sense.

   - Is there a way NOT to create a separate page for each category?
   - How do you query listings by multiple categories? Would this work: `[sabai-directory category="chocolate,arizona,phoenix"]`, with category separated by comma?
2. **Custom fields**. I couldn't figure out categories by myself, so I created custom fields to simulate core WP categories. But the problem is I can't find a way to query listings by these custom fields. So if I need `field_state` field to be set to `arizona` or `massachusetts`, how do I limit my listings to either of those values?

   - Is there a way to specify custom fields in shortcodes?
   - Is there an API in Sabai that I can use to query listings directly? What would the post type be? What would the query look like? (*There is no info on this in the docs*)

On the same topic, once you query the listings, how do you display the contents for a single listing? I've tried `[sabai-directory-listing id="?"]` shortcode, but I don't understand where you get the `id` from: `$post->id` doesn't work.

Please let me know if you have any info